# Ubuntu Security Notification for Hypertext Preprocessor (PHP) Vulnerability found

Tags: php7

Ubuntu 22.04.1, the current version of PHP7.4 is `1:7.4.33-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`, I upgraded to `1:7.4.33-5+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1` is still vulnerable.

The bug disappeared when I installed it from the official website:

```
sudo wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.4/libapache2-mod-php7.4_7.4.3-4ubuntu2.18_amd64.deb`
```

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add package with new version `libapache2-mod-php7.4`

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main"
```

But there are several dependent modules without `php7.4-memcache` `php7.4-intl` `php7.4-zip` `php7.4-mongodb`

I tried using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` to install the modules I don't have, but all dependencies and PHP modules again become `1:7.4.33-5+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1` version.

How can I solve these problems?

Comment: Please provide the Ubuntu Security Notice for PHP that impacts 22.04; I only see notices for 20.04 & earlier as impacting 7.4, as 22.04 uses PHP 8.1